# Foreign keys + table inheritance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I have three tables: `organization`, `organization_teams` and `org_users`. Here `organization_teams` is inherited from `organization`. So suppose if a record is added in `organizations_teams` it will get the `organization` table `id` as value for `id` column in `organization_teams`.

`org_users` has foreign key on `id` column of `organization`. Now when I try to insert data in `org_users` it giving me error as below

```
insert or update on table "org_users" violates foreign key constraint "org_users_organizations"
DETAIL:  Key (org_id)=(12) is not present in table "organizations"
```

Why?

Comment: No. Sequences are not inherited.

Comment: This is known caveat: *A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS

Comment: i already have some organizations in Organization tables and some in organization_teams,So org_user have foreign key on organizations.

Answer (score 41):

It's [covered in the user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS).

The short version: you can use foreign keys, or table inheritance, but not both. This isn't inherently impossible, it's just that it's technically quite difficult to implement unique indexes that span inherited tables in PostgreSQL in a fast, reliable manner. Without that, you can't have a useful foreign key. Nobody's successfully implemented it well enough for a patch adding support to be accepted into PostgreSQL yet.

A foreign key can point to a table that is part of an inheritance hierarchy, but it'll only find rows in that table *exactly*. Not in any parent or child tables. To see which rows the foreign key sees, do a `SELECT * FROM ONLY thetable`. The `ONLY` keyword means "ignoring inheritance" and that's what the foreign key lookup will do.

Comment: Would it be 'safe' to only apply foreign keys at the 'leaf' tables of a table inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe If referencing and referenced tables are partitioned on the same key you can have FKs between corresponding partitions. That's about all.

Answer (score 4):

The only workaround i have found is:

1. create function returning trigger for checking existence of some id
   in inherited table
2. create a constraint trigger instead of FK

Answer (score 1):

Completely agree with @Craig Ringer, we can't use foreign keys along with inheritance.

But if we are sure that we are going to insert correct data, and we want to use foreign key in org_users, we can do one thing.

We can create a child table of org_users say org_users_child (with no foreign key) as below

```
CREATE TABLE org_users_child () INHERITS (org_users);
```

Now we can insert data in this child table.

Now if we query over org_users table, we can find desired results.